# "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" does not create a table?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I'm learning Hibernate and I'm getting the following error:

Looks like it keeps complaining about not having a table. `Table 'testdb.student' doesn't exist`

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1441)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:491)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3201)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2411)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
    at utils.JdbcTest.main(JdbcTest.java:28)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3003)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3503)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:589)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1435)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'testdb.student' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1340)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:205)
```

I did some research and changed my configuration accordingly...
My `hibernate.cfg.xml` is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDB</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
        <!-- <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> -->
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My entity is:

```
import lombok.Setter;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;


@Setter
@Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "sid")
    private int sid;

    private String firstname;

    private String lastname;

}
```

The execute script is:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import testPOJO.Student;

public class JdbcTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Student p =  new Student();
        p.setSid(1);
        p.setFirstname("jeff");
        p.setLastname("xi");

        Configuration con = new Configuration().configure().addAnnotatedClass(Student.class);

        SessionFactory sf = con.buildSessionFactory();

        Session session = sf.openSession();

        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(p);

        transaction.commit();

    }
}
```

My `pom.xml` includes:

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>4.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-hikaricp</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

mysql version: `mysql  Ver 8.0.23 for osx10.15 on x86_64 (Homebrew)`

I have been stuck for a couple of hours. And I cannot figure it out... I really need your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things to note here.

Create @Getter in student entity which is missing.

For MySQL8, use `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect`

Comment: It worked! I'm new to JDBC and Hibernate. How do you know I should use `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect`? Is there any resource I can look at? Thanks again!

Comment: Refer documentation.